# Angular Material and Handsontable

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, handsontable

I am trying to use handsontable with angular and ngHandsontable. There seems to be a weird interaction, when the dialog first appears I only see the first column

[image: first load]

then when I select one of these cells:
[image: cell selected]

and finally when an item within a row is changed I get the formatting I am after:
[image]

Has anyone seen anything similar to this and is there anything I can do to get around this apart form hacking the css of handsontable?

js:

```
// ngHandsontable
vm.minSpareRows = 1;
vm.rowHeaders = false;
vm.db = { items: items };
vm.settings = {
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row']          
};

// overflow ellipsis from js
vm.myCustomRenderer = function (hotInstance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    var MAX_LENGTH = 4;

    if ((value + '').length > MAX_LENGTH) {
        value = value.substr(0, MAX_LENGTH) + '...';
    }
    td.innerHTML = value;
}
```

html:

```
 <hot-table settings="vm.settings"
                           row-headers="vm.rowHeaders"
                           min-spare-rows="vm.minSpareRows"
                           datarows="vm.db.items">
                    <hot-column data="id" title="'ID'"></hot-column>
                    <hot-column data="name.first" title="'First Name'" type="'text'" read-only></hot-column>
                    <hot-column data="name.last" title="'Last Name'" read-only></hot-column>
                    <hot-column data="address" title="'Address'" width="150"></hot-column>
                    <hot-column data="product.description" title="'Favorite food'" type="'autocomplete'">
                        <hot-autocomplete datarows="description in product.options"></hot-autocomplete>
                    </hot-column>
                    <hot-column data="price" title="'Price'" type="'numeric'" width="80" format="'$ 0,0.00'"></hot-column>
                    <hot-column data="isActive" title="'Is active'" type="'checkbox'" checked-template="'Yes'"
                                unchecked-template="'No'"></hot-column>
                </hot-table>
```

Comment: Does clicking on a cell or an item within a row populate an object, via an http call for example?

Comment: @camden_kid Not that I know of, the data is a simple static block and I haven't implemented any callbacks. I'll edit above to show the code blocks I've used.

Comment: In your `md-dialog` parameters do you have `preserveScope` set to true?

Comment: @camden_kid no I'm passing a controller through to the md-dialog : controller: 'clientModalController',
controllerAs: 'vm', and passing some locals across.

Comment: I've created a test - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/oLEPpa (I've never used `handsontable` before so bare with me). This example uses the ngHandsontable example - https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable. I notice that it acts in a similar way to your code and it is not in a `md-dialog`.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the behaviour I am experiencing. I notice that if I remove the height and width from this then it gets rid of the first part of the problem...

Comment: Yes. Not sure about the other problem but I'm pretty sure it is not related to `md-dialog`.

Comment: Agreed sorry bit of a red herring putting that in the question I'll take it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117724/discussion-between-bobwah-and-camden-kid).

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this if you unwrap hansontable of md-content, I don't know what happen with hansontable calculation when this create the table, but md-content directive adds an overflow that cause weird behaviors